# unswitch while loop optimization in c

Tags: c, loops, optimization, compiler-optimization

I'm having a hard time optimizing the following while loop by means of **Loop Unswitching**. I have tried applying the example from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching), however I am having a hard time applying it to a while loop. I have the following code:

```
int n = 5,
    m = 5,
    i = 0,
    val = 0;

while (i < n ) {
  j = 0;

  while (j < m ) {
    if (i < j ) {
      val = val + i ;
    }
    else if ( j == i ) {
      val = val - 1;
    }
    else {
      val = val + j ;
    }

    j = j + 1;
  }

  i = i + 1;
}
```

And have tried unswitching it the following way:

```
while (i < n ) {
  j = 0;

  if (i < j ) {
    while (j < m ) {
      val = val + i;
      j = j + 1;
    }
  }

  if ( j == i ) {
    while (j < m) {
      val = val - 1;
      j = j + 1;
    }
  }

  if (i > j) {
    while (j < m) {
      val = val + j;
      j = j + 1;
    }
  }

  i = i + 1;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong.

Comment: You forgot to mention what you are trying to achieve. Is this an [XY Problem?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Printing `val` gives `15`. So you want `∑n` for `n = 1..5`? There are much easier ways to calculate this. But we don't know what you want to calculate.

Comment: Well I have this problem as an assignment. Just trying to get the same result for both the non and unswitched loop and considering that there are none relevant examples online regarding while loops I tried it here.

Comment: Compilerbouw at UvA by any chance? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such loops are best unrolled with the help of pencil and paper. You want the sum of the following grid:

```
           0   1   2   3   4  |   5   n

    0     -1   0   0   0   0  |   0   0
    1      0  -1   1   1   1  |   1   1
    2      0   1  -1   2   2  |   2   2
    3      0   1   2  -1   3  |   3   3
    m      0   1   2   3  -1  |   4   4
```

The grid can be subdivided into three parts: the diagonal, the upper and lower triangles next to the diagonal in the square part and the rectangular block when `n` and `m` differ.

Let's represent the dimension of the grid by means of the square part, `k²` and the rectangular part, `k·r`:

```
    k = min(n, m)
    r = max(m, n) - k
```

Now you can see which sums the three parts contribute:

```
    val = 2·∑(k - i - 1)·i       # two triangles
        + r·∑(i)                 # rectangle
        - k                      # diagonal
```

(All sums run from `i = 0; i < n; i++`.) This sum can be rearranged to:

```
    val = 2·(k - 1)·∑(i) - 2*∑(i²) + r·(i) - k
        = (2·k + r - 2)·∑(i) - 2*∑(i²) - k
```

This reduces your two nested loops two two independent loops to do the sums of the natural numbers and of their squares. Fortunately, these sums can be expressed by simple relations:

```
    ∑(i) = (n - 1)·n / 2
   ∑(i²) = (2·n - 1)·(n - 1)·n / 6
```

You now have a constant-time formula for your resulting sum:

```
    int val(int n, int m)
    {
        int k = (n < m) ? n : m;
        int r = ((n > m) ? n : m) - k;

        return (2*k + r - 2) * (k - 1) * k / 2
              - (2*k - 1) * k * (k - 1) / 3 - k;
    }
```

All this doesn't have anything to do with loop unrolling, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[Loop unswitching according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching) is a compiler optimization so I'm a little confused about why you'd need to do this yourself, but I think this is as good as it gets in terms of breaking apart the for..ifs

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  // j < i
  for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    val = val + j;
  }

  // j == i
  val = val - 1;

  // j > i
  for (j = i + 1; j < m; ++j) {
    val = val + i;
  }
}
```

This is not a loop you can traditionally unswitch because the conditional variable here is the loop variable.

Comment: I also took the liberty of changing your `while` loops to `for` loops.  I recommend the practice; for loops are much easier to reason about.

Comment: It could of course be that this is someone trying to learn/build a compiler and as such do an optimization by hand (as per exercise) to then implement it.